# Hide rows under header in listview onclick

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I created a listview with a few items like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding knownDeviceList}" RowHeight="70" SelectionMode="None" ItemTapped="rowDevice_Clicked" x:Name="MyListView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <AbsoluteLayout HeightRequest="60" Margin="20,5,20,5">
                    <StackLayout Opacity="0.1" BackgroundColor="White"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" 
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />
                    <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" 
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
                        <Grid RowSpacing="0">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="27" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="6" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="27" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                            <controls:IconView Source="{Binding DeviceImage}" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" Foreground="{Binding DeviceImageColor}" />


                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="24" TextColor="White" />
                            <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding StateShown}" FontSize="16" TextColor="White" />

                            <controls:IconView x:Name="btnPower" Source="power" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5"
                                    Foreground="{Binding PowerStateColor}">
                                <controls:IconView.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.cmdTogglePower, Source={x:Reference MyListView}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}" />
                                </controls:IconView.GestureRecognizers>
                            </controls:IconView>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>
                </AbsoluteLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Now this works like I want it, but now I want to add a header above it with the name: `Devices`
Something like this:
[image]

Now in this case I got all the bulb devices, because that is the list that you see above, but how can I show and hide this list when you click on the header and then rotate the arrow at the very end of that header?

Comment: did you try binding your IsVisible property and Icon To your ViewModel?

Comment: You can refer to this thread ：https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/33975/how-to-implement-expandable-collapsible-listview-in-xamarin-forms, here are several ways to achieve it.